# Kubernetes pods crashes when running GitLab Pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

In my Kubernetes cluster I am running GitLab-ee 15.8.0 with a GitLab Runner. This runner is configured for a kubernetes executor and I have mounted the `/var/run/docker.sock` to this runner in the configmap. When running a pipeline which brings up a docker-compose-test.yml, I can see that all pods that exist in kubernetes are starting to crash and are getting restarted. After that I can see that the pipeline is still in the `Running` state, but nor runner is working on it. The last command the runner executed in the pipeline was: `docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml up -d`.

I expected the pipeline to just bring up the docker containers and run the Laravel tests using the database container and the application container, but instead it messes up the Nginx-Ingress resource.

I am running GitLab-ee:15.8.0 with the gitlab-runner version 15.8.2

Here is the gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:20.10.16

services:
  - docker:20.10.16-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD: "docker-compose -f docker-compose-test.yml"
  

stages:
  - test
  - build
  

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker-compose --version
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD down --volumes --remove-orphans
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD up -d
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD exec -T -e APP_ENV=testing laravel-api-test ./scripts/wait-for.sh database-test:54321 -t 60 -- echo "Database connection established"
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD exec -T -e APP_ENV=testing laravel-api-test php artisan passport:keys
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD exec -T -e APP_ENV=testing laravel-api-test php artisan migrate
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD exec -T -e APP_ENV=testing laravel-api-test sh -c "vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests $PARAMETERS --coverage-text --colors=never --stderr"
    - $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD down --volumes --remove-orphans
  # only:
  #   - tags

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - export IMAGE_TAG=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
    - docker build -t laravel-api:"$IMAGE_TAG" .
    - docker login -u "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME" -p "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL"
    - docker push laravel-api:"$IMAGE_TAG"
  only:
    - tags
```

And this is the docker-compose-test.yml that seems to mess things up:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  laravel-api-test:
    build:
      args:
        user: laravel
        uid: 1000
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/development/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    ports:
    - ${APP_PORT}:9000
    networks:
    - application

  database-test:
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    ports:
    - 54321:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
    networks:
    - application

networks:
  application:
    driver: bridge
```

The last thing that is probably relevant is the gitlab-runner config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: gitlab-runner-config
  namespace: gitlab-runner
data:
  config.toml: |-
    concurrent = 4
    [[runners]]
      name = "Runner_1"
      url = "https://gitlab.project.com/ci"
      token = "my-token"
      executor = "kubernetes"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "gitlab-runner"
        privileged = true
        poll_timeout = 600
        cpu_request = "1"
        service_cpu_request = "200m"
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
            name = "docker"
            mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
            host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
```

Finally this the output from the pipeline after it crashed:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.8.2 (4d1ca121)

on Runner_1 eNNz4y9k, system ID: r_y3jEhmF8fN58

Preparing the "kubernetes" executor

00:00

Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab-runner

Using Kubernetes executor with image docker:20.10.16 ...

Using attach strategy to execute scripts...

Preparing environment

00:04

Waiting for pod gitlab-runner/runner-ennz4y9k-project-117-concurrent-0f24cx to be running, status is Pending

Running on runner-ennz4y9k-project-117-concurrent-0f24cx via gitlab-runner-56cd6f4bb5-zrbd9...

Getting source from Git repository

00:01

Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...

Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/Clients/opus-volvere/laravel-api/.git/

Created fresh repository.

Checking out 3890412c as main...

Skipping Git submodules setup

Executing "step_script" stage of the job script

$ docker-compose --version

Docker Compose version v2.6.0

$ $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD down --volumes --remove-orphans

Container laravel-api-database-test-1 Stopping

Container laravel-api-laravel-api-test-1 Stopping

Container laravel-api-database-test-1 Stopping

Container laravel-api-laravel-api-test-1 Stopping

Container laravel-api-database-test-1 Stopped

Container laravel-api-database-test-1 Removing

Container laravel-api-laravel-api-test-1 Stopped

Container laravel-api-laravel-api-test-1 Removing

Container laravel-api-laravel-api-test-1 Removed

Container laravel-api-database-test-1 Removed

Network laravel-api_application Removing

Network laravel-api_application Removed

$ $DOCKER_COMPOSE_CMD up -d

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile

#1 transferring dockerfile: 827B done

#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore

#2 transferring context: 88B done

#2 DONE 0.1s
```

I am not really sure where to look, with log files or anything, so some help regarding the debugging of this issue is really appreciated...

As far as I can see, the only starts when I try to launch the docker compose. I already built the image in the pipeline and that worked like it should, but it start to go wrong when I actually try to run the containers. Maybe that helps? This is just a really annoying problem that isn't my real expertise or anything so I am reading, learning and trying a lot :(

I followed [this](https://adambcomer.com/blog/install-gitlab-runner-kubernetes/) tutorial on how to add a gitlab runner to kubernetes. Maybe is has something to do with the fact that it tries to create a new pod for the pipeline, because the tuotial I sent says:

> The second is a ServiceAccount, Role, and RoleBinding to give the
> Runner the privileges to add new Pods to the Namespace.

Again, I am not familiar with all this stuff, so for me its also a shot in the dark, but I really want this fixed so I can continue working on this project

What could cause this GitLab pipeline to crash my entire kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never expose the host container runtime to workload inside the cluster.
This can lead to the situation that the GitLab runner "cleans up" and removes the containers that operate your cluster components.

In addition to that you get tied to a specific container runtime which should be an implementation detail of your cluster.

As an alternative you can use docker-in-docker for the GitLab runner for example.

Comment: So I should not mount the docker.sock inside the gitlab runner?

Comment: Exactly, don't do that, run a separate docker-in-docker for it.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding something correctly, but for `DinD` to work, do I need to run a new deployment or something next to the gitlab-runner or is it something already inside the gitlab-runner. I read alot about changes in docker version `18.09` where you do or do not need the dind? Right now I have removed the socket mount, but now I get: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`. I think I need to change the docker_host env right?

Comment: I added an attribute `tls_verify = false` to `[runners.kubernetes]` and added `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"`, but I still got: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: You need to run a docker instance as part of the runner. Depending on the method you can then either share the socket of that docker daemon (not the hosts!), use localhost as docker host or provide the dind as kubernetes service.

Comment: Just to be sure, with "running a docker instance as part of the runner", you mean creating a new deployment in my cluster that runs docker in the same namespace as my gitlab runner?

Comment: That is one option, the other is to add a dind container to the runner pod definition as runners.kubernetes.services

Comment: I tried to run a docker-dind deployment with a service that forwards the 2375 port to the deployment, but I can't get that to work. Could you provide an example of how I can add the pod definion as runners.kubernetes.services. When running as seperate pod I get this error: `error during connect: Get "http://docker-svc:2375/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dlaravel-api%22%3Atrue%7D%7D&limit=0": dial tcp: lookup docker-svc on 10.152.183.10:53: no such host`

Comment: I think this is better suited in a different question.

Comment: Okay I have put the problem in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75460620/gitlab-pipeline-not-connecting-to-dind-pod